# Создание обертки вокруг JPanel

Tags: java, swing, наследование, jpanel

Мне часто нужно создать JPanel с BoxLayout. Поэтому я решил создать класс Column, пронаследованный от JPanel, в конструкторе которого будет устанавливаться нужный мне layout.

```
public class Column extends JPanel {
    public Column() {
        this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    }
}
```

Но при добавлении на окно моих панелей они не отображаются (если Column заменить на JPanel, то всё хорошо)

```
JFrame window = new JPanel();
window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
window.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
external_layout = new SpringLayout();
window.setLayout(external_layout);

Column panel = new Column();
panel.setBackground(Color.RED);

window.add(panel);
window.pack();
window.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: ну все из-за этой строчки в констркторе. я не знаю, что вы хотели сделать, но так нельзя : this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS)); закомментируйте ее и все будет отображаться

Comment: @Дмитрий А что в этой строчке не так? Я хотел навесить на панель BoxLayout.  Когда тогда это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема не в том, что вы не можете навесить BoxLayout. Тут все верно. Вы про контент забыли. Это же BoxLayout, который построит компоненты по оси У. Только компонентов у вас нет. А если нет компонентов, то нет и панели. Попробуйте так, чтобы понять, как это работает:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SpringLayout;

public class Column extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7253422675894324827L;

    public Column() {
        super();
        this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        this.add(new JLabel("test"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        SpringLayout external_layout = new SpringLayout();
        window.setLayout(external_layout);
        JPanel panel = new Column();        
        panel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        window.add(panel);
        window.pack();
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Да, точно, спасибо :)